# Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении перед словом "поможет"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Как правильно отправить работника в командировку и не сделать ошибок из-за
> неправильного оформления и несоответствия нормам поможет серия наших
> семинаров.

Comment: Правильно отправить? Если отправляющий направляется в командировку, он себя отправляет?

Comment: Вопрос по пунктуации, а не по стилю.

Comment: Желаю успеха в отработке пунктуации.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 1):

Это безграмотное предложение. Разговор о пунктуации неуместен. Вставьте в начало "Понять, ", тогда запятая нужна.

Comment: М-м... [**"Понять, ",**] — запятая перед закрывающими кавычками? **Так** не может быть.

Comment: С чего это вдруг? В кавычках я заключаю фрагмент текста, который нужно вставить. И запятую тоже надо вставить. Всё я правильно показал человеку. Вынеси я эту запятую за кавычки, и это уже будет некорректный ответ на вопрос. Автор и так путается с запятыми, не хватало, чтобы он вставил одну запятую, но, воспользовавшись неполным ответом, не учёл другую. Тут не до формальностей. Важна иллюстративность и точность.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая обязательна, чтобы закрыть придаточное предложение. Но необходимо другое слово:
*Как правильно отправить работника в командировку и не сделать ошибок из-за неправильного оформления и несоответствия нормам, **подскажет** серия наших семинаров.*

Или без "как" и с другим порядком:
*Серия наших семинаров поможет правильно отправить работника в командировку и не сделать ошибок из-за неправильного оформления и несоответствия нормам.*

Answer (score 1):

Запятая-то нужна, но стиль такой, что даже в пунктуации разобраться непросто.
Две конструкции "как правильно отправить работника в командировку" и "не сделать ошибок из-за неправильного оформления и несоответствия нормам" категорически не желают становиться однородными - у них  настолько разное управление... Тут даже не столько стиль, но самоё грамматику надо править...

Вариант @ТретийГлаз - получше для понимания, но все равно далек от хорошего стиля.

Ну вот что-то такое (в первом приближении) я бы еще стерпел.
***Разобраться, как правильно направить работника в командировку и как избежать ошибок [неправильного] оформления и несоответствия нормам, поможет серия наших семинаров***

Да и то... "Правильно" и "неправильное" в одной фразе - стилистический ляп, перегрузка, но чем заметить - не знаю